Is it possible only to pick month and year in MudBlazor DateRangePicker?
Is it possible to pick the month and the year in the DateRangePicker? The DatePicker has this functionality, so you don't need to pick a day to successfully apply the filter.
Can someone tell me, if there is a way to solve this problem?
I tried a few methods just like "OpenTo", "FixDay", ...
I searched through the whole MudBlazor documentation but it didn't help me.
(https://mudblazor.com/api/daterangepicker#properties)
<MudDateRangePicker @bind-DateRange="FilterDatumRange"
                     OpenTo="OpenTo.Year"
                     FixDay="1"
                     Label="Datum">
</MudDateRangePicker>

Here I expect the DateRangePicker to set the day and therefore I no longer have to select the day. That's not the case. The year selection is shown to me first, but at the end I still have to select start and end days.

I had the same issue and I found this: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/6163#issuecomment-1385116495
If I understand correctly, the combination of "FixDay" and "OpenTo" settings will result in the desired behavior
<MudDatePicker Label="From" @bind-Date="from"
OpenTo="OpenTo.Month"
FixYear="DateTime.Now.Year"
FixDay="1"
DateFormat="MMM" />'


Just fix the day, open to year and change date format:
<MudDatePicker Label="Year-Month Picker (Fixed Day)" 
               HelperText="@_yearMonth?.ToShortDateString()"
               @bind-Date="_yearMonth" 
               OpenTo="OpenTo.Year" 
               FixDay="1" 
               DateFormat="yyyy/MM" />

